# Is there a stat for number of missed "open look" shots in an NBA basketball game?

Tags: statistics, nba

After watching the NBA finals tonight, I started wondering which team would have won if every player who missed an "open look" shot had made it. I can't find any stats on this. I'm guessing that it's because "open look" is subjective. Short of re-watching the whole game and tallying them myself, is there a way to figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a stat for number of missed “open look” shots in an NBA basketball game?

Not for a specific game that I was able to find, but NBA.com appears to have this statistic [over a period of time](http://stats.nba.com/league/player/shots/#!/?Season=2015-16&SeasonType=Regular%20Season).

[image: How to get to the League Player Tracking Shots page]

From NBA.com/Stats -> Player Stats -> Player Tracking Shots, you'll find yourself on the "League Player Tracking Shots" page.

[image: League Player Tracking Shots page]

From here, under "Closest Defender" or "Closest Defender (+10 FT)," you can choose to filter statistics based on your definition of "open look" (which I'm assuming would fall under "Open" or "Wide Open"). From here, FGA minus FGM will give you "missed 'open look' shots" per game.

For example, Stephen Curry missed 4 "Open" shots per game during the 2015-2016 NBA Playoffs<sub>[(1)](http://stats.nba.com/league/player/shots/#!/?sort=FGA&dir=1&ShotDistRange=&CloseDefDistRange=4-6%20Feet%20-%20Open)</sub>.

Comment: Good link.  In the filtering options, you can change it to "Last Game" or "Last X Games".  It's convenient then that the interest here is in the last game of the season...if you wanted to know it for a specific game in say, February, that might be more difficult to get.

Comment: @Dr.DrfbagIII That's a good point. I was hoping these would be buried in box scores, but alas, no.